# why is my firstname.lastname@gmail.com email on SparkPost policy_rejection list?

Tags: email, sparkpost

Sparkpost blockem my email in the form of firstname.lastname at gmail.com.

I am getting:

> 554 5.7.1 recipient address suppressed due to customer policy

Why would sparkpost block private email addresses like that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has really absolutely **NOTHING** to do with programming .....

Comment: I've asked here becuause this is what I am getting from SparkPost API. Should I ask this on serverfault instead?

Comment: Shouldn't you be asking **SparkPost** directly, instead??

Comment: They're don't seem to be very open about this. I was hoping to get feedback from other uses who may have had similar problems.

Comment: If this question is in some way improper please adivse me and I shall delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that the address is in your suppression list. Addresses get added automatically based on hard bounces, unsubscribes, and spam complaints.

SparkPost are entirely open to questions. You can [contact support](https://support.sparkpost.com/customer/portal/emails/new), or sign up to the [community Slack](https://sparkpost-community.slack.com/) and ask there. (You don't even need to ask because if you do a search in Slack you'll see this question has been answered many times.)

Also, you can read the [support documentation](https://support.sparkpost.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1929891-using-suppression-lists?b_id=7411) about Suppression Lists, and look at the Suppression List [API docs](https://developers.sparkpost.com/api/#/reference/suppression-list).